# How to pass column name as parameter in standard SQL BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to pass column names as parameters in standard SQL Bigquery so that I do not need to hard code the column names. How can I do that?
I need to do something like :

```
@column_name = "Origin";
SELECT @column_name FROM table
```

Comment: if BigQuery is anything like T-SQL then `DECLARE` a parameter and then `SET` it to your column name

Comment: keywords like DECLARE are not accepted by BigQuery

Comment: BigQuery uses standard SQL 2011 according to documentation

Comment: The relevant [feature request is in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905569).

Comment: Note that even with query parameters, however, you would not be able to pass a parameter in place of a column name, just in place of an expression.

Comment: Will it not be possible to pass column name as parameter in SELECT statement of SQL Bigquery

Comment: It will not be, because that defeats the point of query parameters, which help prevent against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2015, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759628/setting-big-query-variables-like-mysql) seems to be:

> There are no 'variables' to be set in BigQuery, but you could add a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B).

From the same thread, it seems you can use [Datalab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/) to use Python variables with BigQuery.

Also, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42628367/how-to-set-named-parameter-on-bigquery-query?rq=1) about using SQL API.

Comment: As of Dec 2016, bigquery standard SQL supports parameterized queries: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#December_22_2016