# bigquery SQL to create a macro variable (or parametrised automated variable)

Tags: google-bigquery

seeking information:

I wanted to know if it is possible to create a macro variable (parametrised) in Bigquery.

Similar to SAS examples like:

%LET tempvar = ('x1','x2'.....'xn')

which I can CALL whenever needed in further SQL clauses.

Any info appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Big Query variables like mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759628/setting-big-query-variables-like-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve you might be able to use UDFs for that, but in general BQ does not support the parameter feature as MYSQL does.

check [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions)

Comment: thanks to FKrauss and Pentium10 for your suggestions.

Comment: Pentium10 - The @corpus example would not run in the web UI - which is what I have to use at work unfortunately....however the WITH example was good for now  - which is what I went ahead with : WITH params AS (select ('x','y','z') as prod1, ('a','b','c') as exclude_list....(until I defined all my regularly used parameters)...),   so thanks a lot for the link - it will do until I learn how to do it with a STRING udf

Comment: unfortunately using WITH to create some parameters didn't work as suggested in the link
The BQ validator was green so good to go - but the 'where' statement didn't work.
Tried using 'IN' instead of '=' as prod_cat1 is a list of values but was getting error
message stating "expecting UNNEST...." but with '=' the validator shows green but it doesn't work
Also I put "" around the parm values to avoid nesting

Comment: (THE QUERY) AS FOLLOWS: with parms AS 
(
SELECT "('pd001','ws008','pf003')" AS prod_cat1,
       "('pd001','ws008')"         AS prod_cat2,
       "('pf003')"                 AS prod_cat3,
       "('purchase')"              AS buy_trans
),

mytable AS
(
select
    id,
    date,
    prodvar
from `DBtable`, parms
where prodvar = prod_cat1
  and event = buy_trans
)
SELECT * FROM mytable

Comment: any suggestions appreciated